# mysql query for timezone conversion

Tags: sql, database, mysql, jdbc

is there a way to convert from unix timestamp to GMT in mysql while running the query itself??
My query is as follows:

```
SELECT
    r.name
  , r.network
  , r.namestring
  , i.name
, i.description
  , r.rid
  , i.id
  , d.unixtime                  // this is the unix time i am asking to print
  , d.ifInOctets
FROM range AS r
INNER JOIN intranet AS i
ON r.rid = i.rid
INNER JOIN 1279080000_1_60 AS d  
ON i.id = d.id
AND unixtime BETWEEN 1279113600 AND 1279115400   // range of unix time
WHERE r.network = "ITPN"
AND i.status = "active"
GROUP BY i.id AND d.unixtime
```

I was working with it in jdbc and tried numerous ways suggested in this forum to do the conversion but it does not seem to help.

Can I convert it directly and print out while running the query itself?
I want to display the date in hour:minutes. eg: 9:20.

Please help or if there is any link I can follow that would be great too.
Thank you,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using [FROM_UNIXTIME](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime) converts a UNIX timestamp to a MySQL DATETIME:

```
FROM_UNIXTIME(r.unixtime)
```

Then you can use [CONVERT_TZ](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz) to get the DATETIME in a different timezone:

```
CONVERT_TZ(FROM_UNIXTIME(r.unixtime), ?, 'GMT')
```

Problem is, you need to know the original timezone is - you have to update the `?` with the correct timezone...

Comment: hi, the from_unixtime worked like a charm. but is it possible to just get it in hours and minutes rather than the whole date,hour,min, second ??
thanks a lot :)

Comment: @jillika iyer: See update - the example I gave will return the value in h24:mm

Comment: that does not work. I get 'null' as the field content then. :(

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime