# Using IST time in mysql query

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have a table containing datetime field. I want to select records with a condition that only those records that has datetime value above current IST time.

Example

```
select * from mytable where dt > current_ist_datetime
```

`current_ist_datetime` is what i do not know how to use. [CONVERT_TZ()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz) with [NOW()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now) can give it. But i do not know what timezone mysql uses. that is, i do not know second parameter that i should pass to `CONVERT_TZ()`

Comment: MySQL will use the current server timezone, to know that you can do a query to it with `SELECT NOW()` for example. That is given you're not the owner of the server or have access to the server.

Comment: so `dt` value is considered to be of current timezone too? i mean database timezone? sample value of `dt` is `2013-06-09 15:50`

Comment: Like spencer replied, it will be either the server current time and/or setted timezone within MySQL variables.

Comment: thank you.How we can set timezone for a single query ?

Comment: See this reply http://stackoverflow.com/a/3499250/342740 and a different approach would be http://stackoverflow.com/a/13204583/342740

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the timezone setting for the current MySQL session with a SQL statement:

```
mysql> SELECT @@session.time_zone;
```

If the DBA has not set the timezone on MySQL, it will default to a value of `SYSTEM`, which represents the timezone on the operating system.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html

---

### FOLLOWUP:

In a predicate as in your example SQL statement:

```
select * from mytable where dt > current_ist_datetime
```

(given `dt` and `current_ist_datetime` of datatype `DATETIME`)
the comparison of the values will be independent of any timezone conversion, since there is no no timezone information associated with a `DATETIME` value.

That is, the value returned from a column of datatype `DATETIME` is not affected by the time_zone setting of the MySQL server (`SELECT @@global.time_zone`) or of the MySQL session (`SELECT @@session.time_zone`).

The value returned by the `NOW()` function, however, will be impacted by the time_zone setting of the session.

To get that returned in IST, ensure the time_zone for the session is specified correctly, e.g.

```
SET VARIABLES time_zone = "+05:30"
```

(N.B. If the session is retrieved from and returned from a connection pool, the other users of the pool may not be expecting a different time_zone;...)

(NOTE: the above entirely ignores the confusion introduced by the JDBC driver, caused by the "impedance mismatch" (differences) between MySQL's implementation of DATETIME datatype, and Java implementation of Date object. If you are passing DATETIME values across a JDBC connection, that's whole 'nother ball of confusion.)

Comment: the `dt` column values are in this format: `2013-06-09 15:50`. This value as well as `NOW()` value has to be in IST. Then i will compare. So `dt` value will be considered to be of current timezone too when doing comparison?

Answer (score 0):

MySQL uses timezone in two formats; i.e. you can either use 'Asia/Calcutta' or '+05:30' (for IST). But I would suggest you use the latter one.

Timezone for UTC is '+00:00'. So you can use following query provided that `dt` is in `UTC` & `current_ist_datetime` is in `IST`

```
select * from mytable where dt > CONVERT_TZ(current_ist_datetime,'+05:30','+00:00')
```

I am using this query in my project where I paas `current_ist_datetime` & `+05:30` from client(in IST) to my server(in UTC) & it works like a charm.

If you use `NOW()` mysql will select current date time of your system's timezone

```
select * from mytable where dt > CONVERT_TZ(NOW(),'+05:30','+00:00')
```

You can modify these queries according to your need.