# how to convert NOW() into IST in mysql

Tags: mysql, datetime

```
table_orders - orderid, customerid, order_datetime (type is datetime)
```

I am entering data in table like this:

```
insert into table_orders values (1, 2, NOW())
```

Time zone on server is not IST and i am not allowed to set time_zone on server. Executing this query gives error.

```
SET time_zone = 'IST';
```

Now() - stores datetime in server time zone.

I want it to store in IST. So My question is how to convert NOW() into IST before DB entry.

Comment: when in doubt use unix timestamps!

Comment: Hmmm. Is that Irish Standard Time, Israel Standard Time, or Indian Standard Time?  [Time zone abbreviations are not unique!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_time_zone_abbreviations).

Answer (score 0):

try using SET VARIABLES time_zone = "+05:30" instead of using 'IST'
or you can refer this [Using IST time in mysql query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17009543/using-ist-time-in-mysql-query) . Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for response. After executing above query select NOW() from dual gives me - 2015-09-27 01:29:58 on server. But on my machine it gives 2015-09-27 03:59:58. Any idea how to add +11:30 in now()

Comment: You can use CONVERT_TZ() from mysql;refer this documentation https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz